# Hub requirement for building matter virtual or physical device

Tags: google-smart-home, matter-iot-standard

The code lab at (https://developers.home.google.com/codelabs/matter-device-virtual?hl=en#0) lists the requirement for "a hub, which is any Google Nest device that supports Matter, such as the Nest Hub (2nd generation)".

At this page: https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/12391458?hl=en
It is listed that following devices can work as a hub.
Wi-Fi routers: Nest Wifi Pro (Wi-Fi 6E)
Speakers: Google Home, Google Home Mini, Nest Mini, Nest Audio
Displays: Nest Hub (1st gen), Nest Hub (2nd gen), Nest Hub Max

In the first link it is mentioned a nest device can act as a hub.
In the second link, it is mentioned google home/home mini can act as a hub but I guess the home/ home mini is not nest.

So I was wondering whether a device such as google home mini or google home can work as a hub in the code lab. I guess google home/ home mini is not nest.

I am trying to find a cheaper option therefore I was wondering if home/home mini can be used as a hub.

Thank you very much for your support.

Answer (score 0):

This is just some kind of linguistic confusion. Google Mini works fine but it does not yet support thread. More information in this regard can be found [here](https://developers.home.google.com/matter/supported-devices#hubs).

Answer (score 0):

I was working on the same codelab, and I found that a hub is not strictly necessary. Once the virtual device is up and running, I utilized the [Google Home Sample App for Matter](https://developers.home.google.com/samples/matter-app#what_are_matter_fabrics) to commission and control said virtual device.